# What is the best way to generate test cases for erlang applications?

Tags: erlang, common-test

Now I'm engaged in creating test cases for application writing on Erlang.
I use common-test for it. This tool is useful and suits me.
But most of the tests have the same structure and sometimes contain the same code.
So, I have a lot of 'copy/paste'. It's not good. 
Would like to optimize my work.
Probably, somebody had the same problem and found a solution.
Please, help me!

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

- Refactor your test code so that the common structure is a separate function that is reused by each test. [Wrangler](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/wrangler/Wrangler/Home.html) can help you refactor any Erlang code automatically, including tests.
- Switch over to [EUnit](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html) so that you can use [Test generating functions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html#Writing_test_generating_functions).

Answer (score 1):

EUnit http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html

QuviqCheck - http://www.quviq.com/products/erlang-quickcheck/ - Good introduction can be found here: http://roberto-aloi.com/erlang/notes-on-erlang-quickcheck/

ProPer https://github.com/manopapad/proper/ - is a QuickCheck-inspired open-source property-based testing tool for Erlang

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I understand QuviqCheck used for test data generating. Am I right?

Comment: Should also mention Proper, a GPL:ed QuickCheck clone: https://github.com/manopapad/proper/